# How would you do this in a DIV?

Tags: html, css

Tried everything, with ul's... div's... but it doesn't appear how it should do.

The main div has margin 0 auto. The main div is 1030px width.

I bet it's a stupid thing...

[image: Image in DIV]

Comment: Sorry, cannot get to your link location.  Please can you describe what you are after.

Comment: @j08691, missed a `;)`. It was a joke

Comment: @Banana, im a newbie.

Comment: @user3560968 "How would you guys do this in a DIV? i tried everything"  is not a question my friend. ask specifically what you need.

Comment: The answer is below @Banana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rcjau/)

HTML

```
<div><span>Things to Know</span></div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
    text-align:center;
}
div:after{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    border-top:1px solid grey;
    top:-10px;
    height:1px;
    content:'';
}
div span{
    background:white;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```